# How can I use DBus to set different wallpapers on each monitor in KDE Plasma 5.13.2

Tags: python-3.x, dbus, kde-plasma

I have multiple monitors on which I want to set a different wallpaper and the best way I can figure out is to use dbus.

I've found a [few snippets on the net](https://github.com/bharadwaj-raju/libdesktop/issues/1) that almost do what I want, however this puts the same wallpaper on all of my monitors. When I modify it like below, the *newkdecommand* string updates *{monitor_loop}* appropriately and the index is in range (it errors if I set it outside of the number of monitors I have) but it doesn't update the desktop wallpapers (they stay the same as before).

[According to the documentation](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting#Activities_and_desktops), desktops() should return an array of all desktops that currently exist. I just cannot reference them in a way that I can set a different wallpaper for each one. Below is the code that I currently have:

```
kdemonitorloop = 0

for monitor in monitors:
    newkdecommand = """
    qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript '
        var allDesktops = desktops();
        d = allDesktops[{monitor_loop}];
        d.wallpaperPlugin = "org.kde.image";
        d.currentConfigGroup = Array("Wallpaper",
                                 "org.kde.image",
                                 "General");
        d.writeConfig("Image", "file:///{save_location}")
    '
    """
    saveloc = "/home/me/Kbgswitcher/testimg_" + str(kdemonitorloop) + ".png"
    os.system(newkdecommand.format(save_location=saveloc, monitor_loop=str(kdemonitorloop)))
    kdemonitorloop += 1
```

Update: on further investigation it appears that the desktops use non-sequential numbers. On my system the containments are 1, 11 and 12 for the middle, left and right screens respectively. I wonder if this is the case for others or if it just chooses random numbers for them?

Comment: I've been viewing this issue too, that "feature" is not documented at all and so I opened [a question in kde forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=305&t=153217).
It seems that the only way to check what desktops/screens are available is to use an interactive console or to ask the user if the screen changed, both of these options are non-automatizable (as even the dbus solution can't return feedback to the caller).
I don't have any solution yet, but in python you can use the dbus package instead of pasing trough the console.
Keep me updated if you find anything